# Bootstrap datetimepicker:: how to set minimum year?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

i'm using [bootstrap datetimepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/). And i have a field to select year in my form. Actually it is just for selecting the year in **YYYY format**(4 digit) . And i'm inserting the selected 4 digit year in MySQL. In mysql database, I'm using ***year Type*** for the column. According to the MySQL Reference,

***YEAR(4) and YEAR(2) differ in display format, but have the same range of values. For 4-digit format, MySQL displays YEAR values in YYYY format, with a range of 1901 to 2155, or 0000.***

so i need to disable the years before 1900 in the bootstrap datetimepicker.

Here is the image of the datetimepicker that i'm using now.

[bootstrap datetimepicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNyBh.png)

Comment: set minimum date as 1/1/1900

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker(minDate : '1900-01-01');
```

Check codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mVOjRQ

Comment: You used bootstrap date picker. Not "eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker"

Answer (score 0):

You can try this constraction:

```
minDate:'-1900/01/01'
```

Comment: i got a warning  from moment.js

Comment: Deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date. This is discouraged and will be removed in upcoming major release. Please refer to https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407 for more info.